# how can I create a turn based app with firebase in android without having a login functionality? Closed

Tags: java, android, firebase, 2d-games

I want to make a TicTacToe game with the help of firebase in Android.
And I don't want to Register/Sign-up any user.
I want user to see the list of Online player and then Invite them from that screen and move to gaming Screen.
how can I achieve this functionality?
[closed]

Answer (score 3):

To be able to identify a user, it's easiest to sign them in with Firebase Authentication. But if you don't want the user to enter any registration details, you can sign them in with Firebase's [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth) with a single call:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously();
```

From that point on, the user is signed in, and has a UID, which you can use identify them and their moves, secure access to their data, and more.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase allows this to have security rules in place and still user can access the firebase db as anonymous User. You can read more from this link:

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth